# How to open and close popups automatically with certain time period

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I am making a web page, in which I have to open a popup window and it should remain open for a time period of 8 seconds(8000 ms).

After this time period that popup should be closed. Then again after 4 seconds I need to open same popup window for another 8 seconds.

I want to put some delay(4 seconds) before a popup open and closes automatically, and the popup window must be remain opened for 8 seconds

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function call()
        {
            popup = window.open('http://www.google.co.in');         
            setInterval(function() {wait();},4000);
        }   
        function caller()
        {
            setInterval(function() {call();},5000);
        }
        function wait()
        {
            popup.close();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="caller();">
</body>
</html>
```

I am familiar with java script functions like `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` but I've found none of them useful in this case.
I've also allowed my browser to open Popups, but this script opens a popup window and closes it as fast as time passes.
Please help me to find out the glitch in my code.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close automatically a webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621554/how-to-close-automatically-a-webpage)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is looking good in formatting but try to put some efforts on your code.
Try to use it as given below, Here is your whole code, I've tried it on my system, and it is **working**.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function call()
        {
            popup = window.open('http://www.google.co.in');         
            setTimeout(wait, 8000);
        }   
        function caller()
        {
            setInterval(call, 12000);
        }
        function wait()
        {
            popup.close();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="caller();">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try these:

```
function call() {
    popup = window.open('http://www.google.co.in');         
    setTimeout(wait, 8000); // closes the pop-up after 8 secs delay
}

function caller(){
    setInterval(call, 12000); // opens a pop-up on every 12th second
}
```

Your current `call()` creates a new interval every time it's executed.

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning your intervals to any variables, without having a reference to these intervals they will continue running indefinitely with no way of clearing them. A method of doing what you want would probably be better with setTimeout as the periods between opening / closing and then re-opening are all different, also you have no problems with constantly running intervals. The below code creates a loop that will run indefinitely until you want it to stop.

```
var popup = {
    open : function()
    {
        // Open popup
        this.popupWindow = window.open('http://www.google.co.in');

        // Return a timeout function
        return setTimeout(function() {
            // run close function on completion of timeout
            popup.close();
        }, 8000);
    },
    close : function()
    {
        this.popupWindow.close();
        // Assign timeout to local variable
        this.timeout = this.loop();
    },
    loop : function()
    {
        var self = this;

        // On first run open popup immediately, or wait 4 seconds and restart
        // the loop
        if (self.active === true)
        {
            return setTimeout(function() {
                self.timeout = self.open();
            }, 4000);
        }
        else
        {
            self.active = true;
            self.timeout = self.open();
        }
    },
    clearLoop : function()
    {
        clearTimeout(this.timeout);
        this.active = false;
    }
};

popup.loop();
```

to stop the loop at anytime you can call

```
popup.clearLoop();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can close the popup window after a particular interval using this below code

```
 <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="spk_button" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(function(){window.close()},3000);">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it as a "scenario":

```
function next(state) {
  switch(state) {
    case 0:
      showPopup();
      setTimeout("next(1);",8000);
    break;
    case 1:
      hidePopup();
      setTimeout("next(2);",4000);
    break;
    case 2:
      showPopup();
      setTimeout("next(3);",8000);
    break;

    ...etc...

  }
}

/* this you have to call at start */
function init() {
  next(0);
}
```

If you need in some step to repeat cycle, you can of course use next(0).

And of course there have to be functions showPopup and hidePopup

Comment: This solution is extremely redundant. I am not sure it's a really good idea ! The Teemu answer seems better and avoid making a lot of not needed tests. You can read this if you want : http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/how-to-avoid-switch-case-syndrome/
Anyway, you know exactly what is the next "case" of the switch that will be called, so I don't think the switch statement is the good one for this case.

Comment: I agree, this is redundant - but it is universal. Of course it can be written better, where f.e. scenario steps are declared as array or object…